# How do I swipe to delete table cell to update on parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am able to delete the row in my tableview. But I would like to do the same for the information on parse.com. any suggestions as to how I could go about this?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        usernames.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You have information from your Parse account in your tableview. You want to delete information from Parse when you delete it from the tableview? If so, you could just delete it after your `tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: what would be the code for it?

Comment: You will need to use `.delteInBackground()` on the PFObject this might just delete every object in the class

Comment: i tried it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: Could you post the code for your tableView data source?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `usernames` is an array of PFObject's (perhaps PFUser's), then you just need to add `usernames[indexPath.row].deleteInBackground()` right after `tableView.beginUpdates()`